# Reassign window.orientation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, orientation

I'm working with an iframe inside a page and the page and iframe are on different domains.  The site is intended for mobile devices, so I am passing the window.orientation property of the page to the iframe via an html post message.  That is working, but now I need a way to assign the iframe's window.orientation property to the value received from the post message.  Is it possible to reassign window properties like .orientation and if so how?

All help is appreciated.

Edit:  The purpose of this is to get css media queries to the device's orientation to work from within in the iframe.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by reassigning that value? What should change through that?

Comment: I am trying to get media queries to the device's orientation to work.  Such as: @media (orientation: landscape).

Comment: Ah, OK. You might should mention that in the question to give it a sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be a solution to your problem.

**JS**

```
var currentWidth = 0;

function updateLayout() {
    if (window.innerWidth != currentWidth) {
        currentWidth = window.innerWidth;

        var orient = currentWidth == 320 ? "profile" : "landscape";
        document.body.setAttribute("class", orient);
    }
}

setInterval(updateLayout, 400);
window.addEventListener("resize", updateLayout, false);
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", updateLayout, false);​
```

**CSS**

```
.profile{background:#f00}
.landscape{background:#00f}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GQd3x/)**